# Spring. Удалить таблицу

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Как мне удалить таблицу reports так, чтобы из records.report_id удалился id? Ну, то есть, удалить report так чтобы не удалялись связанные таблицы.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reports")
public class Report {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "report")
    private List<Record> records;
    



@Entity
@Table(name = "records")
public class Record {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Report report;
```

Сейчас, как бы, когда я делаю:

> private final ReportRepo reportRepo;

> reportRepo.deleteAll();

То получаю ошибку:

```
2021-08-06 15:21:01.967  INFO 26287 --- [on(1)-127.0.0.1] 

o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 5 ms
2021-08-06 15:21:09.381  WARN 26287 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
2021-08-06 15:21:09.381 ERROR 26287 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: update or delete on table "reports" violates foreign key constraint "fknsdciwyfwp2ermy0q8wqcoh41" on table "records"
  Подробности: Key (id)=(2122) is still referenced from table "records".
2021-08-06 15:21:09.384  INFO 26287 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-08-06 15:21:09.574 ERROR 26287 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fknsdciwyfwp2ermy0q8wqcoh41]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "reports" violates foreign key constraint "fknsdciwyfwp2ermy0q8wqcoh41" on table "records"
  Подробности: Key (id)=(2122) is still referenced from table "records".
```

Comment: у связи OneToMany смотри CascadeType

Answer (score 0):

Единственный вариант, который я нашел - это делать всё вручную:

**В модели**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "records")
public class Record {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Report.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "report")
  private Report report;
```

**В контроллере**

```
    new ArrayList<Record>((Collection<? extends Record>) recordRepo.findAll()).forEach(record -> record.setReport(null));
    reportRepo.deleteAll();
```

Перед удалением главной таблицы обнулить id везде, где я хочу.